# How to show that $(p \wedge q) \to (p \to q)$ is a tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics

hi can any one help me on this question please

Show that the conditional statement $(p \wedge q) \to (p \wedge q)$ is a tautology.

I tried to solve it, but I can not. 
\begin{align*}
& \equiv \neg(p \wedge q) \vee (p \to q) \tag{Implication}\\
& \equiv \neg(p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \vee q)  \tag{Implication}\\
& \equiv (\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee (\neg p \vee q)  \tag{De Morgan}\\
& \equiv (\neg p \vee \neg p) \vee (\neg q \vee q)  \tag{Commutative Associative}\\
& \equiv (\neg p \vee \neg p) \vee T  \tag{Negation}
\end{align*}

How can I complete it?

Comment: You have completed it... $\phi \lor T \equiv T$ for every formula $\phi$.

Comment: Aside from the non-descriptive title, I have absolutely no idea why this is getting downvotes. This is a completely legitimate question.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  I edited the title to make it specific to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To finish it, use $$a \vee T = T.$$

(I just noticed that Mauro ALLEGRANZA answered before me, albeit as a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct, the objective is to get True, so you can use idempotence for $\neg p \lor \neg p \equiv \neg p $ . Finally by dominance property in proposition logic you have: $\neg p \lor V \equiv V$. This is a tautology and final step.